# Upvotes not counted

Tags: discussion, reputation

On July the 7th I gave a well received [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1457032/763386), at this time 85 upvotes but when I look at my reputation I see many upvotes not counted, only 35 are considered.

Here is a capture of my reputation page:

[image]

Can someone explain me this strange behaviour?

Comment: Reputation gain is capped at 200 per day (with a couple of exceptions that get counted even if you hit 200).  If you're looking at the reputation breakdown, it will show the votes that got counted toward your rep.

Comment: You've got nearly 70,000 rep on [so] and this is the first time you've noticed the reputation cap?

Comment: @Mokubai: I've never got such amount of upvotes on a single day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> “I see many upvotes not counted, only 35 are considered.”

You have been repcapped:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily reputation limit.

Source [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: OK, I see. Are all theses rep over 200 lost or added on the following days?

Comment: @Toto They are just never counted.